# Change style attribute with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table row of a calendar that I need to go on and off according to the month.

HTML:

```
<tr id="bottomrow" class="week" valign="top" style="display:none;">
        <td class="day" id="d36">
            <div class="daynumb" id="x36"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="day" id="d37">
            <div class="daynumb" id="x37"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="day" id="d38">
            <div class="daynumb" id="x38"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="day" id="d39">
            <div class="daynumb" id="x39"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="day" id="d40">
            <div class="daynumb" id="x40"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="day" id="d41">
            <div class="daynumb" id="x41"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="day" id="d42">
            <div class="daynumb" id="x42"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

I tried using `document.getElementByID('bottomrow').style.display = "none";` but it doesn't seem to be working...

JavaScript:

```
function february() {

document.getElementById('bottomrow').style.display = "none";

var numbdays = 28,
    offset = 5;

for (var date = 1; date <= numbdays; date++) {
    document.getElementById("x" + (date + offset)).innerHTML = date;
}
}
```

When the page loads, the row is still visible. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are never calling your function. put <script type="text/javascript">february();</script> at the end of the html document

Comment: Please view: http://jsfiddle.net/ryfitzger227/eJxaK/

Comment: Works in the fiddle, don't see your problem sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it correctly except `getElementByID` is not a function.  It has to be `getElementById`.  Notice the lowercase `d`:

```
document.getElementById("bottomrow").style.display = "none";
```

Comment: Thank you... Can't believe I missed that. Haha.

Answer (score 0):

Is the function running before the DOM is ready? It can't operate on elements that don't exist yet.

```
window.onload = function ()
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: You can still bind to the ready event of the document and you probably need to. The other option is to add your JS at the very end of the page.

Comment: Put the code below the html or in a function which is called after load of the html like body onload="" or smiliar

Comment: Lots of ways to go about it. I've added one to my answer.

Comment: It's nicely hidden in that demo, Ryan. Be aware that JSFiddle runs scripts onload by default.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the proper handling of the ready event for the page because the DOM elements haven't loaded on the page yet. jQuery abstracts this but take a look at this post on how to do it without jQuery or another library. You need to be sure to handle the differences in browsers which the following guide will do.

[$(document).ready equivalent without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery)